# ArcGIS 10.3 Feature To Polygon tool not working over dateline

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I am working in ArcGIS for Desktop 10.3. I have a set of closed polylines that are building several distinct areas in the Pacific. The goal is to make polygons from these lines. The Feature To Polygon tool in the Data Management Tools works fine for all closed lines not crossing the dateline. However, it is not working when lines are crossing the dateline (180 degree). I get empty outputs with the warning: 'error 000117'. I tried working in different projections (GCS WGS84, PlateCaree-centered at 180 degree) and I changed the working extent to my needs, as recommended in the ArcGIS Help to no avail. I am aware that I can edit new polygons and trace the lines to achieve my goal. Is there an automated way I can change a set of closed lines, that cross 180 degree, into a polygon using ArcGIS?

Comment: Did you reproject the data itself or simply change the data frame's coordinate system?

Comment: As @FSimardGIS implies, try reprojecting the polylines into a Pacific-centered projected coordinate system, then building the polygons. If that doesn't work, try converting polylines to points, project to PCS, build as polygons.

Answer (score 1):

I reprojected the polylines to a Pacific-centered PCS and now "Feature To Poygon" works fine. Before, I didn't reproject the data itself, just changed the data frame's coordinate system as @FSimardGIS 's question implied.
Accordingly, I had to reproject the line files to different polar projections for my polygons in the arctic/antarctic regions. Thank you for the help @FSimardGIS and @mkennedy.